# Facebook App Website Login

Tags: facebook

I have created a facebook app to allow users on my website to invite their facebook friends. However, my site does not use SSL (https), and when facebook does the redirect upon clicking on the notification (John has invited you to try xyz.com), it attempts to redirect to https://www.xyz.com instead of http://www.xyz.com and prevents users from accessing my site.

In my app settings on Facebook, I have configured the url to be http://www.xyz.com so I'm not sure why this is happening?

Comment: I am same problem, Facebook friend invite does not show any notification on friend wall.